# how to display fetched json data into listview using baseadapter

Tags: android, json, listview

I am new to android and java.Recently I am having problem with displaying fetched json data into listview using baseadapter.
At first I have used this code

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   new TheTask().execute();
  }
     class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
  {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String str = null;
    try
    {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BSDI/show.php");
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return str;

  }



@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    String response = result.toString();
    try {


        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);

        for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i< count; i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                stringArray.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());


            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>   (MainActivity.this,R.layout.test_tuh,stringArray);            
        ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        //tv.setText("error2");
    } 


}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

This code displays fetched json data sucessfully. But it only displays only one row. I need more than one (two) rows in listview. So I have tried this code 
and it does not work, it shows a blank screen .

My code is below,

```
 class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
  {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String str = null;
    try
    {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BSDI/show.php");
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return str;

  }


@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    String response = result.toString();
    try {
         arrayList=new ArrayList<get_set>();

        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);



        for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i< count; i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                stringArray.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());


            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



   ListView listView;
    adap= new BaseAdapter() {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
            if (view==null) {
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bsdi, null);
            }
            TextView title_tuh=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);
            TextView notice_tuh=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notice1);


            title_tuh.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            notice_tuh=.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNotice());
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.size();
        }
    };


    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adap);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        //tv.setText("error2");
    } 


}
```

As far I am realizing that , the problem is here

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);



        for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i< count; i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                stringArray.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());


            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

As far I am guesing that extracted json data is storing in stringArray but its not used later. If I try to use it like this , then I get error

```
title_tuh.setText(stringArray .get(position).getTitle());
notice_tuh=.setText(stringArray .get(position).getNotice());
```

If I try to not to use 
    ArrayList stringArray = new ArrayList();

and use
    arrayList=new ArrayList(); instead , like this then I also get error.

```
    arrayList=new ArrayList<get_set>();


        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);


        //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i< count; i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());
               // String in = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I can not finding out how to solve this problem.I have seen many online tutorials but those was not helpful for me. Please help me.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I have tried to fetch json data and display it into listview. I have successfully fetched json dta from PHP and displayed it into single row listview. But I need to display it into multiple row list view. My problem is here. I want to display multiple row listview . In every row , 1st line will be "title" and second row will be "notice" . I have shared above codes for giving you an idea what I have tried , and so that you can find out where is my fault

Comment: here u need to implement BaseAdpater instead of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: if you guide me with simple code , then it would be helpful for me .

Comment: Tutorial to build listView with BaseAdapter using JSON fetched using Retrofit2 service https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multiple-columns-listview-from-json-data-using-retrofit2-in-android-example/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First u need t create `row_listitem.xml` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_icon_social"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:src="@drawable/sms_t"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_icon_social"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ttlsm_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ttlcontact_row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:maxEms="20"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Sample text2"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, u need to create **Custom BaseAdapter** like:

```
  public class BaseAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
// private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
private static ArrayList title,notice;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public BaseAdapter2(Activity a, ArrayList b, ArrayList bod) {
    activity = a;
    this.title = b;
    this.notice=bod;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return title.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);

    TextView title2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlsm_row); // title
    String song = title.get(position).toString();
    title2.setText(song);


    TextView title22 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row2); // notice
    String song2 = notice.get(position).toString();
    title22.setText(song2);

return vi;

}
```

}

Now, u can set up your **main activity** like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> title_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> notice_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView list;
BaseAdapter2 adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new TheTask().execute();
}

class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String str = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/BSDI/show.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    String response = result.toString();
    try {


        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i < count; i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                title_array.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());
                notice_array.add(jsonObject.getString("notice").toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        adapter = new BaseAdapter2(MainActivity.this, title_array, notice_array);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        // tv.setText("error2");
    }

}
}

 }
```

Comment: thanks. But after running the app , it crashes.After trying about an hour I failed to find out the reason.  Do you have any solution about that?

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin post your logcat

Comment: After trying today I have fixed that. BTW thank you very much for your help. Its now working perfectly .

Comment: @SimplePlan how did you fixed this? I'm getting JSONException: End of input at character 0

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin how did you fixed this? I'm getting JSONException: End of input at character 0

Answer (score 2):

@Allen Chun , actually its not in my mind currently that what I have changed in my code to run my code perfectly. But I am sharing all my codes which are working perfectly.

Its my layout code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fsr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Notice Board"
    android:textSize="20px" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/err_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 

    android:id="@+id/list_notice2"

    android:layout_gravity="center" />




</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom listview layout codes,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

its my activity named "NoticeBoard" .

```
public class NoticeBoard extends Activity {


ArrayList<String> title_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> notice_array = new ArrayList<String>();

ListView list;
base_adapter3 adapter;
 TextView f,msg;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_notice);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_notice2);
    msg=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.err_msg);
    new test_ays().execute();
}




class test_ays extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String str = null ;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BSDI/show.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();



        }
        return str;


    }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result!=null) // add this
    {  
     String response = result.toString();


   try {

        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i < count; i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                title_array.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());
                notice_array.add(jsonObject.getString("notice").toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        adapter = new base_adapter3(NoticeBoard.this, title_array, notice_array);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
       // f=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTuh);
       // f.setText(title_array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();

        // tv.setText("error2");
    }
    }

    else{
        msg.setText("You need a working data connection...");
    }


}
}

}
```

And its my custom baseadapter codes,

```
public class base_adapter2 extends BaseAdapter {


    private Activity activity;
    //private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
    private static ArrayList title,notice;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public base_adapter2(Activity a, ArrayList b) {
      activity = a;
      this.title = b;
     // this.notice=bod;

      inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
      return title.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View vi = convertView;
      if (convertView == null)
          vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bsdi_adapter, null);


      TextView title2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt1); // title
      String song = title.get(position).toString();
      title2.setText(song);



    return vi;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I am connecting to Twitters public timeline JSON url.

```
package net.inchoo.demo.andy1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()));        
    }

    public ArrayList<String> fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()
    {
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL twitter = new URL(
                    "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json");
            URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listItems;
    }
}
```

Please direct your attention on the **listItems.add(jo.getString(“text”));** line. This is the part that I am grabbing a “text” attribute/property of single JSON object. To get a more “visual” picture of all available attributes/properties you might want to take a look at the XML version of twitters public timeline. This way you will get nice colored XML in your browser, where you can see all available attributes.

Link: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/android-development/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity/

Answer (score 0):

Json parser:

```
public class jparser {

static InputStream istream = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
//static JSONArray jarray=null;
static String json = "";
//static JSONArray jarray = null;

// constructor
public jparser() {
}

public JSONObject getJFromUrl(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    //try {
        // defaultHttpClient
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        /*HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        istream = httpEntity.getContent();*/
        try{
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

         if (statusCode == 400) 
         {
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

           InputStream content = entity.getContent();

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

           String line;

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
           {
             builder.append(line);
           }
         } 
         else
         {
             Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
         }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        istream.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

   // Parse String to JSON object

     /*try {
            jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jarray;

    }*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get schedule

```
public class GetSchedule extends Activity {

    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_SNO = "sno";
    private static final String TAG_STNCODE = "stnCode";
    private static final String TAG_STATION = "station";
    // private static final String TAG_ROUTENO= "routeNo";
    private static final String TAG_ARRIVALTIME = "arrivalTime";
    private static final String TAG_DEPTIME = "depTime";

    private JSONArray station = null;

    private ListView list;
    //private static String url = "http://railpnrapi.com/api/route/train/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_schedule);

        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stnNamelist = new    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Getting JSON Array
            // JSONObject job = new JSONObject();
            //JSONArray jArray = ModuleClass.trainScheduleJSONObject.getJSONArray("stnName");
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            station= ModuleClass.trainScheduleJSONObject.getJSONArray(TAG_STATION);
            for (int i = 0; i < station.length(); i++) {
                json_data = station.getJSONObject(i);

                // JSONObject c = stnName.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

                String sno = json_data.getString(TAG_SNO);
                String stnCode = json_data.getString(TAG_STNCODE);
                // String distance= c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                // String routeNo = c.getString(TAG_ROUTENO);
                String arrivalTime = json_data.getString(TAG_ARRIVALTIME);
                String depTime = json_data.getString(TAG_DEPTIME);
                // String haltTime = c.getString(TAG_HALTTIME);
                // String tday= c.getString(TAG_TDAY);
                // String remark = c.getString(TAG_REMARK);
                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                stnNamelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_SNO, sno);
                map.put(TAG_STNCODE, stnCode);
                map.put(TAG_DEPTIME, depTime);
                map.put(TAG_ARRIVALTIME, arrivalTime);
                // map.put(TAG_DEPTIME,depTime );

                stnNamelist.add(map);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                final SimpleAdapter sd;
                sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, stnNamelist, R.layout.activity_get_schedule, 
                        new String[] { TAG_SNO, TAG_STNCODE, TAG_ARRIVALTIME, TAG_DEPTIME },
                        new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4});
                list.setAdapter(sd);
                /*
                 * list.setOnItemClickListener(new
                 * AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                 * 
                 * @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
                 * view, int position, long id) { Toast.makeText(
                 * MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +
                 * stnNamelist.get(+position).get( "name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 * .show(); } });
                 */
            }
            // Set JSON Data in TextView
            // uid.setText(id);
            // name1.setText(name);
            // email1.setText(email);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get_schedule, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            public class JSONParser {

                static InputStream is = null;
                static JSONObject jObj = null;
                static String json = "";

                // constructor
                public JSONParser() {

                }

                // function get json from url
                // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

                    // Making HTTP request
                    try {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        // check for request method
                        if(method == "POST"){
                            // request method is POST
                            // defaultHttpClient
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();

                        }else if(method == "GET"){
                            // request method is GET
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                            url += "?" + paramString;
                            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();
                        }


                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        json = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // try parse the string to a JSON object
                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // return JSON String
                    return jObj;

                }
            }


        <h1>Model</h1>
        public class WorkModel {

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getImagename() {
                return imagename;
            }

            public void setImagename(String imagename) {
                this.imagename = imagename;
            }

            String id,name,imagename;

            public WorkModel(String s1,String s2,String s3)
            {
                this.id=s1;
                name=s2;
                imagename=s3;
            }
        }

    <h1>listview fill</h1>
    public class Work_in_process extends Fragment {

        //////////////jsonparser implement
        JSONParser jsonparser=new JSONParser();
        JSONArray json_users=null;
        JSONObject json;
        /////////

        ListView lst;
        ArrayList<WorkModel> data=new ArrayList<WorkModel>();
        WorkAdapter adapter;
        Context con;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work_in_process, container, false);
                con=this.getActivity();
                lst=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.work_listview);

                new work_process().execute();

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return rootView;
        }

        class  work_process extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
        {
            public Dialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                data.clear();
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("your url","POST", params);

                try {
                    int success = json.getInt("status");
                    if (success == 0)
                    {
                        return  "kbc";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        json_users = json.getJSONArray("result");
                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < json_users.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = json_users.getJSONObject(i);
                            String t1 = c.getString("id");
                            String t2 = c.getString("work_title");
                            String t3 = c.getString("image_path");
                            WorkModel da=new WorkModel(t1,t2,t3);
                            data.add(da);
                        }

                        return "abc";
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equals("abc"))
                {
                    adapter = new WorkAdapter(con, data);
                    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

<h1>Adapter fill listview</h1>
public class WorkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater1=null;
    private static String string=null;
    ArrayList<WorkModel> data=null;
    Context activity;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public WorkAdapter(Context act,ArrayList<WorkModel> da)
    {
        activity=act;
        data=da;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            inflater1=(LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi=inflater1.inflate(R.layout.list_work,null);
        }

        TextView name;
        ImageView img;
        name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_work_name);
        img= (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_work_img);
        WorkModel da=new WorkModel(string,string,string);
        da=data.get(position);

        final String p1,p2,p3;
        p1=da.getId();
        p2=da.getName();
        p3=da.getImagename();

        name.setText(p2);
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));

        final String imgpath=""+p3;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();

        imageLoader.displayImage(imgpath, img,options);

        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DisplayImageOptions options;
                final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                final Dialog emailDialog =new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
                emailDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                emailDialog.setCancelable(true);
                emailDialog.setContentView(R.layout.zoom_imge);

                ImageView image = (ImageView) emailDialog.findViewById(R.id.zoom_image_img);
                emailDialog.show();

                final String imgpath=""+p3;
                options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.wp_loading)
                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisk(true)
                        .build();

                imageLoader.displayImage(imgpath, image, options);
            }
        });




        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ListView** from **JSON** data fetched using **Retrofit2** service

**JSON response**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Olivia"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Isla"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Emily"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Amelia"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Sophia"
    }],
  "statusCode": "1",
  "count": "2"
}
```

[image]

In **MainActivity.java** we will pass JSON data as ArrayList(**dummyData**)

```
    customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dummyData);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listShowJSONData);
    listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

In custom **BaseAdapter** our

```
...
...
@Override
public MyModel getItem(int i) {
    return this.users.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view==null)
    {
        view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.json_data_list,viewGroup,false);
    }

    TextView mUserDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userDetails);
    TextView mUserStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userStatus);


    Object getrow = this.users.get(i);
    LinkedTreeMap<Object,Object> rowmap = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
    String name = rowmap.get("name").toString();
    String phone = rowmap.get("phone").toString();

    mUserDetails.setText(name);
    mUserStatus.setText(phone);

    return view;
}
...
...
```

Here **MyModel** will be used as custom mapping model of response we will get from service

**See [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multiple-columns-listview-from-json-data-using-retrofit2-in-android-example/) for complete code explanation**