# How to load JSON data into Android Listview?

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I want to load JSON data into the List view with subtitle and images (Left side on the row).

Here below I have posted my sample JSON response code :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator keys = obj.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {

      // loop to get the dynamic key
       String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();

       // store key in an arraylist which is A,B,...
       // get the value of the dynamic key
       JSONArray currentDynamicValue = obj.getJSONArray(currentDynamicKey);
       Log.d("Response: ", "> " + currentDynamicKey);



      int jsonrraySize = currentDynamicValue.length();
         if(jsonrraySize > 0) {
             for (int ii = 0; ii < jsonrraySize; ii++) {
                  JSONObject nameObj = currentDynamicValue.getJSONObject(ii);
                  String name = nameObj.getString("name");
                  System.out.print("Name = " + name);
                  //Log.d("Response: ", "> " + name);

                  //store name in an arraylist
             }                    
         }
      }
}
```

I want to Show `Tittle : currentDynamicKey` values and `Sub Title : Name` string values.

Comment: Check : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display fetched json data into listview using baseadapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662673/how-to-display-fetched-json-data-into-listview-using-baseadapter)

Comment: try google .there are lot of examples

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your data and you don't necessarily need to integrate the server requests with your adapter, then you really just need an adapter which supports a JSONArray.  There's a really nice open source one within the [Advanced-Adapters](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) library.  Then it's just a matter of passing the JSONArray to the adapter and setting the adapter to a `ListView`.